# Linux + PHP Автоматизированный поиск файла в директориях выше

Tags: php, массивы, файлы, строки

> основная директория

`MAIN`

> дочерняя директория

`MAIN/сontent/`

> файл который содержит в себе строку:

`content1.txt` //файл

```
images/images1.jpg
```

> дочернаяя директория с вызываемыми скриптами

`MAIN/script/`

```
$a = '/content/content1.txt';
$a = file_get_contents($a);
echo $a;
```

> Задача : Сделать так, что бы, php выполнил следующие инструкции.

```
Поиск файла => 
=> Файла нет в текущей директории => 
=> Перейти в родительскую папку => 
=> Искать там => прочитать => выдать содержимое.
```

Подумал и нашел 3 варианта ответа :

> 1 - использовать в скриптах chdir по условию.
>
> 2 - задать абсолютный  путь вида  ../content/content1.txt;
>
> 3 - написать свою функцию для автоматизирования процесса.

**Вопрос , Возможен ли 4й вариант?** 
Может есть готовая функция выполняющая эти условия , либо другой способ.

Answer (score 1):

воспользовался 3м вариантов

```
class extended 
    {

public function rd($path) 
 {
$dirpath;
$dirchange = '../';
if(file_exists($path)) {
$text = file_get_contents($path);
echo $text;
goto end;
}
do {
     if(file_exists($fullpath)){
        $text = file_get_contents($fullpath);
        echo $text;
        goto end;

    }
    $dirpath = $dirpath . $dirchange; 
    $fullpath = $dirpath . $path;


    } while ($dirpath !== '../../../../../');
 if(!file_exists($fullpath)) {echo 'file not exists';exit();}

end:
}

}

$etrinity = new extended();
$etrinity->rd();
```